# Generator of Lie Group cohomology in degree 3

Tags: lie-groups, cohomology, at.algebraic-topology

This is my first question.

Take a simple, connected, compact, simply connected Lie group $ G$ (dim $G\geq 3$).
The cohomology of $G$ with integer coefficients is
$H^{1,2}(G,\mathbb{Z})\cong 0$, $H^{3}(G,\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}$.
I'm looking for a generator of $H^{3}(G,\mathbb{Z})$.
It should be something of the form $\alpha K(\theta,[\theta,\theta])$, where $\theta$ denotes the left Maurer-Cartan-Form, $K$ is the Killing-Form and $\alpha$ is a scaling factor.

Comment: Set $\sigma(x,y,z):=cK([x,y],z)$ such that $cK(h_\alpha,h_\alpha)\in 2\mathbb{Z}$ for each coroot $h_\alpha$ of G. Then $[\sigma]\in H^3(G;\mathbb{Z})$. This is proved in Loop Groups by Segal-Pressley (page $49$).

Comment: If I am not mistaken, any subgroup of $G$ isomorphic to $SU_2$ induces an isomorphism $H_3(SU_2;\mathbb Z)\cong H_3(G;\mathbb Z)$. Now topologically $SU_2$ is just a 3-sphere, so each such subgroup can be viewed as an integral 3-cycle, and this 3-cycle will thus represent a generator of $H_3(G;\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: I think the answer in Pressley, Segal might be off by a factor of $48 \pi^2$. See my question on Stack Exchange for the discussion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3603441/normalization-of-the-generator-of-third-cohomology-of-a-compact-lie-group?noredirect=1#comment7409287_3603441

Answer (score 9):

The third cohomology group of the Lie algebra (with coefficients in the trivial module) is generated by the cocyle $\phi(x,y,z)=K(x,[y,z])$. The usual proof that the de Rham cohomology of the group is the same as the Lie algebra cohomology of the corresponding Lie algebra gives you a more or less explicit $3$-form generating $H^3_{\mathrm{dR}}(G,\mathbb R)$. It gives you a generator of integral cohomology up to scaling. I don't know what the factor should be, though...

Comment: Is there an explicit formula for the scaling factor?

Comment: @mikethspike Something like $1/2\pi$ or similar (perhaps an $i$ in there as well).

Comment: The scalar is a cute invariant of the group. Hopefully there is some more precise description than that :)

Comment: I thought there was a 1/12th in there, but I'm blanking on where I saw that.